# Setting proxy authentication on ServiceMix

Tags: apache-servicemix

I have ServiceMix installed behind a web proxy, and I need it to call a web service over the Internet.

I tried setting the proxy settings within my code with

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost" .....
```

(ugly and hacky, I know)
as well as setting the

```
http.proxyHost=myproxy
http.proxyPort=8080
http.proxyUser=myuser
http.proxyPassword=mypassword
```

in the etc/system.properties file of ServiceMix.

None of that worked.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since your using ServiceMix you most likely are using Camel with CXF to call this webservice. 
You need to set this proxy in your Camel context especially for CXF by setting the http-client configuration. Take a look at this [link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html), it shows you how to configure the http conduit of CXF. 
I'm sure your also able to set the proxy this way.

Comment: I do use Camel, but I am using a ProducerTemplate that takes a url, so I don't think Camel goes through CXF.

I wonder if I should make changed so I use CXF, but I am not sure I have the time to make all the necessary changes, and my url's are dynamic, based on responses from previous requests.

Comment: So what are you doing? Are you sending raw xml requests to the other servers? Then How do you do this, by using the commons http-client. I'm quite sure there is a way of configuring it in an analogue way as with the cxf client (it uses the http-client inside)

Comment: Here's what I currently do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984812/proxy-authentication-with-camel-using-producertemplate/16985136?noredirect=1#16985136

I didn't know if anybody would open this question anymore, so I reformulated the question and added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use http:conduit:

```
  <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http:authorization>
      <sec:UserName>Betty</sec:UserName>
      <sec:Password>password</sec:Password>
    </http:authorization>
    <http:client ProxyServer="x.x.x.x" ProxyServerPort="xxxx"/>

  </http:conduit>
```

See: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html